# One cell content (text) as variable in another cell

Tags: openoffice-calc

```
Cell A1=Alice
Cell A2=Adam Love $A$1
```

How can I make the cell A1 content as variable so I could use it in anywhere in my worksheet?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do something special to achieve this; every cell is available by its cell reference `[file].[sheet].[Col][Row]`. The only thing is that you can't just put the cell reference as plain text into another cell - you'll have to **use a [function](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_Functions_listed_by_category) or a [formula](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Creating_formulas)** instead.

In you example, your aim is to **[concatenate](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_CONCATENATE_function)** a string ("`Adam Love`") and the value of another cell. So, the solution is to use the [**`CONCATENATE()`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_CONCATENATE_function) function in the following way:

> =CONCATENATE("Adam Love "; $A$1)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to define a name (Data > Define Range...) say `Name`:

```
_A
```

and `Range`:

```
$Sheet1.$A$1
```

then apply a formula such as:

```
="Adam Love "&_A
```

but for your example the effort of setting up the defined name is unlikely to be justified by savings in keying. However this can at times be useful, for example where sheet names are lengthy or keying them is prone to error (the formula above returns the same result even if on a different sheet) and complicated formula can be easier to read (eg`=Qty*Price`).